# Find beginning of transaction set

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset that is relatively large, for my laptop.
My goal is to achieve the desired output in a reasonable timeframe.  Maybe less than 30 minutes?  Quicker if possible.

Dataset is 800k records and growing.

MySql database.
Prefer to do this with transact SQL, no stored procedures and no cursors.

I was able to do this but it is excruciatingly long, hours.

I've got a table with ping results.
It has been parsed out to flag which pings were successful and which timed out.

| Date_time | Timeout_flag |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:21 | 0 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:22 | 1 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:23 | 1 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:24 | 0 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:25 | 0 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:26 | 1 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:27 | 0 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:28 | 1 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:29 | 1 |

I would like the following result

| Date_time | Timeout_flag | Last_Success |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:21 | 0 | null |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:22 | 1 | 2022-07-16 8:48:21 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:23 | 1 | 2022-07-16 8:48:21 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:24 | 0 | null |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:25 | 0 | null |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:26 | 1 | 2022-07-16 8:48:25 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:27 | 0 | null |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:28 | 1 | 2022-07-16 8:48:27 |
| 2022-07-16 8:48:29 | 1 | 2022-07-16 8:48:27 |

My first approach included a sub-select correlated query where the subselect returned the max(date_time) for records whose date_time < date_time of the outer select.
This took hours.

I toyed with lag() and lead() but couldn't quite get there.

Any thoughts?

---

**08/02/22 - Update - providing example of lag() usage**

---

As I mentioned, I used the lag statement but couldn't get it right.
For example, I implemented this

**This is not the correct output, merely an example starting point I found.**

```
/* This query runs in 20+ seconds against 800k+ records */
SELECT
    ping_date_time
    , lag( ping_date_time, 1 ) 
        over( 
            partition by timeout_flag 
            order by ping_date_time desc 
        )
from
    results_2 r
;
```

| ping_date_time | lag_fct |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-07-29 17:48:49 |  |
| 2022-07-29 17:48:48 | 2022-07-29 17:48:49 |
| 2022-07-29 17:48:47 | 2022-07-29 17:48:48 |
| 2022-07-29 17:48:46 | 2022-07-29 17:48:47 |
| 2022-07-29 17:48:46 | 2022-07-29 17:48:46 |
| 2022-07-29 17:48:45 | 2022-07-29 17:48:46 |
| 2022-07-29 17:48:44 | 2022-07-29 17:48:45 |
| 2022-07-29 17:48:43 | 2022-07-29 17:48:44 |
| 2022-07-29 17:48:42 | 2022-07-29 17:48:43 |
| 2022-07-29 17:48:41 | 2022-07-29 17:48:42 |

Comment: does the verision of mysql you use support analytical functions -> lag/lead

Comment: Yes, I toyed with lag() but I wasn't sure how to get the last success.
All I was able to accomplish was the immediately prior ping_date_time, not the last success

Answer (score 0):

(Note: Please test it out as I am unsure of the performance)

Here is a solution using self-join:

```
SELECT 
    p1.date_time, p1.timeout_flag, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN p1.timeout_flag = 0 THEN NULL ELSE p2.date_time END) AS last_success
FROM ping p1
INNER JOIN ping p2 ON p1.date_time >= p2.date_time AND p2.timeout_flag = 0
GROUP BY p1.date_time, p1.timeout_flag
ORDER BY p1.date_time
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=871e7ab236e553d8708fb72e9f0e3052)

Comment: Thank you very much.
I tried this out and find it similar to my subselect.  The self-join is in fact a better performer though so it is a step in the right direction.

So far it has been running for about 45 minutes.
I will update the description to show the lag example which is almost instantaneous and close to what I want but not exactly